# Second screen after login screen

Tags: html, google-chrome-app

I am currently building a chrome app **NOT an extension** and I cannot get to my  'main screen' after my login. I tried opening just the html file in the browser and it worked but when i used it in the application it failed to open the second screen. I have attached all elements of my code as I am not sure which ones will be helpful in fixing this issue.

*Code is below- only one I didn't attach was the second screen because that is not relevant.*

Login Screen (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head> 
  <body>

<form  action="screen2.html">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="images.jpeg" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

    <button href="screen2.html" type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

  </body>
</html>
```

manifest (JSON):

```
{
  "name": "App that I am building",
  "description": "none",
  "version": "16.3",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "46",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "icon16.png", "128": "icon128.png" }
}
```

Background script (JavaScript):

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 1000,
      'height': 2000
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't navigate the main app page to a different one. You can use an iframe for this.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: Uhm, in the main window.html you have `<iframe>` that points to screen1.html where your entire first page UI is shown and it submits to screen2.html (or navigates via location.href)

Comment: Thank You! I was able to fix the issue. I appreciate your help.